# Chi-squared goodness of fit test.. Where is my error?

Tags: statistics

The types of raw materials used to construct stone tools found at the archaelogical site Casa del Rito are shown below. A random sample of 1486 stone tools was obtained from a current excavation site.

[image]

I'm trying to run a Chi-squared goodness of fit test on this data. Here is a table of my calculations:

[image]

Now I use the formula

[image]

And get $\chi^2=.1829$

The answer key says I should have $\chi^2=.1984$

Anyone see anything I might have done wrong? Or maybe the answer key is wrong?

Comment: A couple of things could be going on. 1) There is a minor error in the tabular data, since the total number of tools is 1487 rather than 1486. 2) I cannot get the same result as you, which may be due to rounding errors on your part? 3) I also cannot get the same answer as the referenced answer key.

Comment: Also, in principle your calculations look fine - but avoid rounding off multiple times along the way in case you have done that, since rounding errors can accumulate.